# How do I accumulate vectors into a map?

Tags: apache-pig

I have an alias `A` like this:

```
{cookie: chararray,
 keywords: {tuple_of_tokens: (token: chararray)},
 weight: double}
```

where the 2nd and 3rd fields are defined as

```
keywords = TOKENIZE((chararray)$5,',');
weight = 1.0/(double)SIZE(keywords);
```

now I want to do

```
foreach (group A by cookie) generate
  group.cookie as cookie,
  ???? as keywords;
```

and `keywords` should be a `map` from a keyword into a the sum of weights.

E.g.,

```
1   k1,k2,k3
1   k2,k4
```

should turn into

```
1   {k1:1/3, k2:5/6, k3:1/3, k4:1/2}
```

I am already using [datafu](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide.html), but I am open to any alternative...

Answer (score 0):

I'd do

`A_counts = foreach A generate cookie,flatten(keywords) as keyword,1.0/SIZE(keywords) as weight;`

then

`A_counts_gr = group A by (cookie,keyword);` and
`result= foreach A_counts_gr generate flatten(group) as (cookie,token), sum(A_counts_gr.weight);`

and then one can group by cookie to get a bag like you want...after grouping by cookie again there will be a bag, than you can turn this bag to a map with datafu...

Comment: `describe result` prints `{id: chararray,token: chararray,double}` there is no `map` (or even `bag`) there.